# Сессия php при авторизации

Tags: php, html

Разбираюсь с сессиями php. Суть такая: я авторизовался на сайте, далее меня перекидывает на другую страницу (main.php). Тут я также авторизован, далее я нажимаю кнопку выхода и уничтожается сессия, меня перекидывает на страницу входа. Не работает кнопка выхода, сколько бы раз не жал и не проверял if'ами и выводами. Что я сделал не так?

```
<?php 
session_start();
require("header.php");
echo ''.$_SESSION['name']; // вывожу для себя 
if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    session_destroy();
?>
     <!--><script>document.location.replace('http://wc2018/index.php');</script>"<!-->
<?php
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
<div class="main">
    <label id="text"><a href="">Команды</a></label>
    <label for="text"><a href="">Игроки</a></label>
    <label for="text"><a href="">Матчи</a></label>
    <button type="submit" name="logout">Выйти</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Вот начало из файла входа]

Answer (score 1):

session_destroy(); не удаляет данные сессии и не очищает их, они снова становятся доступны при вызове session_start(); 
Просто очисти сессию $_SESSION['NAME']=''

Comment: у меня почему-то именно кнопка не работает, не выполняется условие

Comment: Может потому что надо не button а input type=submit и что бы submit отрабатывал ему форма нужна, оберни в form